# Declaring a boolean Variable and Using a callMethod

Tags: java, variables, methods

Thanks so much for your help everyone! I figured it out and got it to run, I think I like to make things more difficult then they really are.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PasswordManager{

private static String masterPassword = "secret3";

public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean mypass = false;
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Password:");
        mypass = checkPassword(password);

        if (mypass == true)
            System.out.println("Your Password is Correct");
        else
            System.out.println("Your Password is incorrect");
}

private static boolean checkPassword(String password){
        if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(masterPassword))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Try researching. The [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) can help a lot, especially [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Are the following methods in a class? Crazy but obvious question.

Comment: every tutorial i have found has led me to only declaring integers and nothing to do with me making sure the masterPassword will allow me to input it and let me know if the password is correct or not using JoptionPane

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String thePassword = "nosecret";

public static void main(String[] args){

    //*** TO DO ***: Declare a variable here of "boolean" type.
    boolean mybool = false;

    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter The Password:");


    //*** TO DO ***: Call the checkPassword method and pass it to the "password" variable
    // from above and assign the result to your boolean variable.
    mybool = checkPassword(password);


}

private static boolean checkPassword(String password){

    //I'm giving you part of this code to show you one way of comparing Strings.  This way ignores case,
    //which may not be appropriate for passwords, but it's a useful method for many other things.
    //Also, I'm giving you the "return true;" part to show you one way a boolean can be sent back...
    //simply as the words "true" or "false" ... notice in code they're not in quotes just like numbers.
    //*** TO DO ***: Add an "else" statement below that returns false.
    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(masterPassword))
        return true;



}
```

Comment: Are you aware that this is a homework assignment? Also, this is Java, not C or C++, etc.

Comment: Note: Declare is not the same as initialize.

Comment: yes I know it's homework. And just realized it was java.  Thanks for the heads up

Comment: you should always initialize...best practice

Comment: I am aware; just thought that maybe the assignment was to declare, not initialize.

Comment: it was to declare the variable, then use the callmethod which is checkPassword.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this may help in `main` method

```
boolean validPass = checkPassword(password);
```

`checkPassword` method can be defined as

```
private static boolean checkPassword(String password) {
    if(password.equalsIgnoreCase(thePassword))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

where `thePassword` is the global variable with value nosecret